# Javascript/HTML - filtrar JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Tengo 3 `JSON`: clinicas, localidad y especialidad, estoy tratando de filtrar por Localidad y por Especialidad con Javascript, la idea es que al seleccionar los 1 o los 2 filtros juntos se oculten imágenes de la página. El problema que tengo es que funciona parcialmente, por ejemplo: si aplico sólo un filtro, no surge efecto hasta que selecciono el segundo filtro. Los JSON de Especialidad y Localidad, los cargo en dos `Select` de `HTML` por separado y el JSON de Clinicas lo uso para cargar imágenes en la página `HTML`.

Dejo un ejemplo en JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k8awudmc/

No se si es la forma correcta de hacer esto, realmente, o si hay alguna alternativa mejor, fue la forma que se me ocurrió implementar, se aceptan sugerencias también.

JSON Clinicas:

```
[
  {
    "idc": "6",
    "ima": "clin-test1.jpg",
    "title": "Clin Test 1",
    "especialidades": "-4-16-",
    "idlo": "1"
  },
  {
    "idc": "11",
    "ima": "clin-test2.png",
    "title": "Clin Test 2",
    "especialidades": "-38-40-41-43-44-",
    "idlo": "2"
  }
]
```

JSON Especialidades:

```
[
  {
    "ides": "4",
    "nom": "Alergista"
  },
  {
    "ides": "6",
    "nom": "Cardiologia"
  },
  {
    "ides": "11",
    "nom": "Cirugia"
  },
  {
    "ides": "40",
    "nom": "Cirugia Bariatrica"
  },
  {
    "ides": "44",
    "nom": "Cirugía Plástica"
  },
  {
    "ides": "1",
    "nom": "Clinica Medica"
  },
  {
    "ides": "8",
    "nom": "Cosmiatria"
  }
]
```

JSON Localidad:

```
[
  {
    "idlo": "1",
    "nom": "Ciudad1"
  },
  {
    "idlo": "2",
    "nom": "Ciudad2"
  },
  {
    "idlo": "3",
    "nom": "Ciudad3"
  },
  {
    "idlo": "4",
    "nom": "Ciudad4"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tenías es que restabas 1 al indice seleccionado. El selectedIndex te devuelve un 0 no hace falta restarle 1. ¿Porque parecía que cuando seleccionabas el segundo filtro funcionaba? Cuando seleccionabas la localidad ese -1 afectaba a especialidad por lo que daba un error y por eso cuando seleccionabas especialidad parecía que funcionaba, ya que ambos filtros en principio tendrían un indice mayor de 0.

```
function aplicarFiltro() {

  var especialidadSeleccionada = document.getElementById("selectEspecialidad").selectedIndex;
  var localidadSeleccionada = document.getElementById("selectLocalidad").selectedIndex;

  //He quitado el menos 1
  var idEspecialidad = dataEspecialidades[especialidadSeleccionada].ides;
  //He quitado el menos 1    
  var idLocalidad = dataLocalidades[localidadSeleccionada].idlo;

  for(var i = 0; i < dataClinicas.length; i++) {
    var idClin = "clin" + dataClinicas[i].idc;
    var clinicaEspecialidades = dataClinicas[i].especialidades;
    var clinicaLocalidad = dataClinicas[i].idlo;
    var ocultarClinica = document.getElementById(idClin);

    if (clinicaEspecialidades.indexOf("-" + idEspecialidad + "-") > -1 && clinicaLocalidad.indexOf(idLocalidad) > -1) {

      ocultarClinica.style.display = 'inline';
    }
    else {
      ocultarClinica.style.display = 'none';
    }

  }

}
```

Otro consejo veo que en el document ready cargas todo , lo mejor es que lo hagas en funciones para que sea más legible.
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder!. Ya veo, justamente le restaba el uno porque tenía la <option> "select". Después en el if, está bien que ponga la condición de > - 1?

Comment: La función indexOf te devuelve el indice de lo que estés buscando, por lo que si no lo encuentra por lo general te devuelve -1, por lo que si esta bien que pongas -1. Si te ha funcionado ponlo como respuesta.

Comment: Ok, al final para resolverlo, además de sacar el -1, tuve que cambiar las variables
"var especialidadSeleccionada = document.getElementById("selectEspecialidad").options[selectEspecialidad.selectedIndex].id;"
"var localidadSeleccionada = document.getElementById("selectLocalidad").options[selectLocalidad.selectedIndex].id;" Para poder acceder al ID del option del select. Y de esta manera funciona corretamente.